# tick typesetter fails with Illegal parameter number when used with beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-datavisualization

I'm trying to change the way ticks are display in tikz datavisualization
(ideally with prefix unit), but for now I'm stuck as specifying a tick typesetter fails when used in a beamer document

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tikz \datavisualization [
  scientific axes,
  x axis={logarithmic},
  y axis={logarithmic,
          ticks={
             tick typesetter/.code={%
                  \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, retain unit mantissa=false]{##1}
                   }
                }
          },
  visualize as line
  ]
  data [format=function] {
    var x : interval [0.01:100]; func y = \value x * \value x;
  };
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `fragile` frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\tikz \datavisualization [
  scientific axes,
  x axis={logarithmic},
  y axis={logarithmic,
          ticks={
             tick typesetter/.code={%
                  \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, retain unit mantissa=false]{##1}
                   }
                }
          },
  visualize as line
  ]
  data [format=function] {
    var x : interval [0.01:100]; func y = \value x * \value x;
  };
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```